# Uploading from server to google colab

Tags: linux, command-line, google-colaboratory

I have a (linux-based) server that I access via SSH that has a bunch of files I want to process in a google colab notebook. I was wondering if there was anyway to directly upload the files from the server to my colab notebook without using my own computer as an intermediate? Using something like rsync/scp or similar.